# Outer command when output is a row vector

Tags: r

So I know that in `R` you can use the `outer()` command to simplify calculations over two grids of values that usually require using a for-loop to evaluate.   For example,

```
x = 1:10
y = 1:10

f = function(x,y){
    ans = x*y
    return(ans)
}

outer(x,y,f)
```

Now, this works since the output of `x[i]*x[y]` for any `i` is a scalar. However, if the output of `x*y` was a vector, can you still apply the `outer()` command in an analogous way?

For example, is there a fast way like `outer()` to calculate all outputs which are vectors for something like the following:

```
x = 1:10
y = 1:10

f = function(x,y){
    ans = x*y+c(1,1,1)
    return(ans)
}

outer(x,y,f)
```

These examples are kind of trivial but I am working on a problem where I have three embedded for-loops that have to loop over a very large number of times to complete every possible combination.

Comment: your code is an error. What do you mean by `*+`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MichaelChirico sorry yeah it was a typo when I copy and pasted over.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're after, but here's a start (assuming `f` is actually `x*y + rep(1,3)`):

```
do.call(mapply, c(f, expand.grid(x=x, y=y)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] ...
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    6 ...
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6 ...
# [3,]    2    3    4    5    6 ...
```

If instead you want three-dimensional output, use `sapply` with `simplify="array"`:

```
sapply(x, function(xx) sapply(y, function(yy) f(xx, yy)), simplify = "array")

# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
# [3,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
# ...
```